# Flutter: Gradle task assembleDebug failed (configuring root project 'android')

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart

I'm using Android studio 3.6.1 on windows 10
(I'm new to flutter and this is my first try)

you can see my "flutter doctor" result here (all check):
[flutter doctor command result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F2Iw.png)

Unfortunately when I want to run my program this error Occurs:
[android studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw5Jg.png)

text:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:2347 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:2347 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I try all articles in Stack Overflow, YouTube and medium but I'm still stuck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced same problem, I resolved by;

```
Delete all files in .gradle folder and reopen Android studio to re-download and update to the latest files.
PATH: C:\Users\<YOUR-USER-NAME>\.gradle
```

This Worked for me. I hope it helps, then re-run flutter doctor command